# Getting multiple plots in one WORD file using "RepoteRs" package in R

Tags: r, plot, reporters

**Background:**

I usually use **ReporteRs package** to get ***"a"*** high quality, vectorized plot as a single WORD file. ***A general R code*** for doing that is presented below. Basically, I wrap the plot up as a function, call it "G" and then ask ReporteRs package to convert "G" into a word file.

**Question:**

I was wondering when **the device layout** is something like:

`m <- matrix( c( 1,0,  1,3,  2,3,  2,0  ), nrow=2, ncol=4 ); layout(m)` (i.e., 3 plots)

is it still possible to get the 3 plots converted into a single word file using ReporteRs package?

```
library('ReporteRs')

doc = docx()

doc = addPlot(doc, fun = G, vector.graphic = TRUE, width = 4.5, height = 4.5,  
par.properties = parCenter(), editable = T, fontname_serif = "Times New Roman", 
fontname_sans = "Times New Roman", fontname_mono = "Times New Roman", 
fontname_symbol = "Times New Roman")

writeDoc(doc, file = "plotname.docx")
```

Comment: A similar issue is reported [here](https://github.com/davidgohel/ReporteRs/issues/168)

Comment: @akrun, thanks, so it's not possible apparently using ReporteRs package. Do you know of any other packages that can handle that?

Comment: Usually, I try with markdown to create documents pdf/doc/html all at once.

Comment: @akrun, so markdown handles multiple plots in a specific place (i.e., wherever you need the plots to be) of a docx file?

Comment: Yes, it is possible by using `par(mfrow=c(1,3))` in your plot code (or using gridExtra::grid.arrange with ggplot objects). There are many docs and ressources about theses 2 options. Then output the plot in a Word document with `addPlot`.